# How to submit a html form in the default browser in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to submit a post form in the default browser in react native. I don't want to use react-native-webview. I tried with Linking.openUrl but it didn't work. Does it have any other way?

Here is a simple code:

```
<form method="POST" target="..." id="..." :action="videoConferenceUrl">
  <input type="hidden" name="target" value="..."/>
  <input type="hidden" name="requestOrigin" value="..."/>
  <input type="hidden" name="username" :value="..."/>
  <input type="hidden" name="password" :value="..."/>
  <input type="hidden" name="eventID" :value="..."/>
</form>
```

Comment: You could use Linking.openUrl with url parameters to a .html page you've created/ hosted that contains the form and some javascript that would auto fill from url params & then submit. If you're looking for form functionality in react native there are packages for that or just collect the data using Inputs and post the data via the fetch api.

Comment: @bryanstevens314 would you show me an example because I only want to submit a post form.